# Correct classes for WordPress menu items

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, menus

I have been trying to get the current menu item to my custom post types. I cannot get it to work, and when looking at my menu, I am wondering, that if everything is allright.

Which are the correct classes WordPress should generate, when displaying pages, archives and custom post types?

I have this link explaning them: http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/wordpress-menu-css/

But my page for example has the following classes:

```
menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-146 current_page_item menu-item-147
```

And my custom post type:

```
menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-187
```

Which seems strange, since the menu is a link to the category and archive page, not a taxonomy?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The link that you posted explain well which classes WordPress generate for menu items. Which class is strange for you in example you have posted? Consider that categories `are` type of taxonomies.

Comment: The taxonomy archive menus have the classes `menu-item-type-taxonomy` and `menu-item-object-{taxonomy-name}`, so there is nothing strange because **category is a taxonomy** (here you are wrong when say that "the menu is a link to the category and archive page, not a taxonomy"

Comment: @cybmeta as an answer please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The taxonomy archive menus have the classes `menu-item-type-taxonomy` and `menu-item-object-{taxonomy-name}`, so there is nothing strange because category is a taxonomy (here you are wrong when say that "the menu is a link to the category and archive page, not a taxonomy").